# OroCommerce 4.1 default theme customization

Tags: sass, frontend, themes, customization, orocommerce

I am trying to create a custom theme following the docs https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/theming/

The source code inside CustomThemeBundle and the FrontendBundle were used as a reference implementation as well.

And I haven't figured out:  **How to replace the font color and size for the top bar?**

All the other changes are working properly: Logo, favicon and the primary main color.

1. **My bundle folder structure**

```
# bundle
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/MyCompanyThemeBundle.php

# config
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/config/oro/bundles.yml

# assets
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/my_theme/favicons/favicon.ico
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/my_theme/images/logo.svg

# styles
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/my_theme/scss/components/top-bar.scss
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/my_theme/scss/settings/_colors.scss
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/my_theme/scss/settings/global-settings.scss
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/my_theme/scss/variables/top-bar-config.scss
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/public/my_theme/scss/styles.scss

# assets config
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/views/layouts/my_theme/config/assets.yml

# theme definition
src/MyCompany/Bundle/ThemeBundle/Resources/views/layouts/my_theme/theme.yml
```

2. **The theme extends default. The logo and favicon are loading ok**

Here is the code for the theme definition: **Resources/views/layouts/my_theme/theme.yml**

```
parent: default
logo: bundles/mycompanytheme/my_theme/images/logo.svg
icon: bundles/mycompanytheme/my_theme/favicons/favicon.ico
label:  My Company Marketplace
description: My Company Marketplace Theme.
groups: [ commerce ]
```

Here is the code for the assets config: **Resources/views/layouts/my_theme/config/assets.yml**

```
styles:
  inputs:
      - bundles/mycompanytheme/my_theme/scss/settings/global-settings.scss

      - bundles/mycompanytheme/my_theme/scss/variables/top-bar-config.scss
      - bundles/mycompanytheme/my_theme/scss/styles.scss
  output: css/styles.css
```

3. **I used the CustomThemeBundle as reference and changed only the main primary color. It works**

Here is the code for the colors imported by *global-settings.scss*: **Resources/public/my_theme/scss/settings/_colors.scss**

```
/* @theme: my_theme; */

$custom-color-palette: (
    'primary': (
        'main': #0165AD, # that was the only color changed and it overrides the default as expected.
        'base': #fd302b,
        'light': #ff7a76,
        'dark': #ce0500
    ),
    'secondary': (
        # all the same from CustomTheme
    ),
    'additional': (
        # all the same from CustomTheme
    ),
    'ui': (
        # all the same from CustomTheme
    )
);

$color-palette: map_merge($color-palette, $custom-color-palette);
```

4. **Now I try to override the top bar color and font size and it DOENS'T WORKS**

Here is the code for the variables of top-bar: **Resources/public/my_theme/scss/variables/top-bar-config.scss**

This file is imported by **assets.yml**

```
/* @theme: my_theme; */

$top-bar-font-size: 14px; #it doens't change the font size
$top-bar-background: get-color('primary', 'main') !default; # it doenn't change the color
```

Here is the code for the top-bar component: **Resources/public/my_theme/scss/components/top-bar.scss**

This file is imported by **styles.scss**

```
/* @theme: my_theme; */

.topbar {
    background: $top-bar-background; # this is the background color I am trying to override

    ...
    # the entiry file content is an exact copy of the default theme from the FrontendBundle
    ...
```

Here is the code for the styles: **Resources/public/my_theme/scss/styles.scss**

This file is imported by **assets.yml**

```
/* @theme: my_theme; */

@import './components/top-bar';
```

5. **What is wrong with the code?**

The commands used to deploy the theme bundle:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console assets:install --symlink
php bin/console oro:assets:build my_theme
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly all `scss` variables in new custom theme have to be without `!default` postfix like:

```
/* @theme: my_theme; */

$top-bar-font-size: 14px;
$top-bar-background: get-color('primary', 'main');
```

Use the following command to build your theme:

`bin/console oro:assets:build -- my_theme`

More information about
[themes build](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/bundles/platform/AssetBundle/#oro-assets-build)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a separate guide on customizing fonts on the OroCommerce storefront:
   https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/how-to/how-to-change-fonts/

   It covers the font-size modification.
2. And also there is a guide on customizing the color schema:
   https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/how-to/how-to-change-color-scheme/

   It should cover the font color customization.

Comment: I've read this documentation and also read the section about the CSS structure:
https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/storefront/css

> This structure enables us to change styles for components on a bundle level, on a component level and for a particular theme. The main idea of this approach is not to override styles in a child theme from the parent one. We just change settings and add additional CSS(SASS).

Comment: 1. How to change the **background color of the top bar** on a component level ?
 2. If I change the color palette: 'aditional': ('light': #0165AD) to be the same of my brand primary color then I will have to change the 'aditional': ('dark': #FFF) to the contrast color of my brand as well. 
3. Do I have to rewrite the entire code for the top bar just to change the background color?
4. The only option to change the top bar color is by changing a global color palette?
5. I still don't understand how the extension of a theme works. The documentation it is not clear on this subject.

Comment: See Valerii's answer for the variables override.